# How do I make a shortcut of a remote desktop connection and include the password?

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop

I want to open a remote desktop connection directly from a shortcut, and I want to embed the username password within the shortcut.

How do I get the path of a remote desktop from an RDP shortcut, and can we set password in an RDP shortcut?

Comment: answer available in steps at : http://stackoverflow.com/a/40017890/4361073

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When saving the RDP file, check off the **Save my password** checkbox. This will save your password to the `.RDP` file in an encrypted format. Be careful though, as people have found out [how to decrypt it](http://www.thincomputing.net/blog/encryption-of-passwords-in-rdp-files.html):

[image]

Comment: how to add password manually to open RDP file in note pad

Comment: This is not a problem anymore with MSTSC v6 - the credentials are stored elsewhere on the system (Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Credentials), and as far as I know, they are encrypted with the user's login password.

Comment: I already have RDP file. I want to edit the file and insert password

Comment: @Jitendra the file stores the password in an encrypted format, it's not as simple as opening it and typing `password:abc123`. If you can find a tool to encrypt them into that format then you can, but I doubt somebody would bother making such a tool.

Comment: There is no option to enter/save password in Windows 7. Can you help?

Answer (score 6):

Try editing the .rdp files directly. I found an article, [How rdp passwords are encrypted](http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2007/10/18/how-rdp-passwords-are-encrypted/), saying how, and deep down, in the posts, there is some code for how to do this in C# too:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

class Mstscpw
{
    private const int CRYPTPROTECT_UI_FORBIDDEN = 0x1;
    // Wrapper for the NULL handle or pointer.
    static private IntPtr NullPtr = ((IntPtr)((int)(0)));
    // Wrapper for DPAPI CryptProtectData function.
    [DllImport("crypt32.dll", SetLastError = true,
    CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern bool CryptProtectData(
    ref DATA_BLOB pPlainText,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string szDescription,
    IntPtr pEntroy,
    IntPtr pReserved,
    IntPtr pPrompt,
    int dwFlags,
    ref DATA_BLOB pCipherText);
    // BLOB structure used to pass data to DPAPI functions.
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal struct DATA_BLOB
    {
        public int cbData;
        public IntPtr pbData;
    }

    private static void InitBLOB(byte[] data, ref DATA_BLOB blob)
    {
        blob.pbData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(data.Length);
        if (blob.pbData == IntPtr.Zero)
            throw new Exception("Unable to allocate buffer for BLOB data.");

        blob.cbData = data.Length;
        Marshal.Copy(data, 0, blob.pbData, data.Length);
    }

    public string encryptpw(string pw)
    {
        byte[] pwba = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pw);
        DATA_BLOB dataIn = new DATA_BLOB();
        DATA_BLOB dataOut = new DATA_BLOB();
        StringBuilder epwsb = new StringBuilder();
        try
        {
            try
            {
                InitBLOB(pwba, ref dataIn);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Cannot initialize dataIn BLOB.", ex);
            }

            bool success = CryptProtectData(
            ref dataIn,
            "psw",
            NullPtr,
            NullPtr,
            NullPtr,
            CRYPTPROTECT_UI_FORBIDDEN,
            ref dataOut);

            if (!success)
            {
                int errCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                throw new Exception("CryptProtectData failed.", new Win32Exception(errCode));
            }

            byte[] epwba = new byte[dataOut.cbData];
            Marshal.Copy(dataOut.pbData, epwba, 0, dataOut.cbData);
            // Convert hex data to hex characters (suitable for a string)
            for (int i = 0; i < dataOut.cbData; i++)
                epwsb.Append(Convert.ToString(epwba[i], 16).PadLeft(2, '0').ToUpper());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("unable to encrypt data.", ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (dataIn.pbData != IntPtr.Zero)
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(dataIn.pbData);

            if (dataOut.pbData != IntPtr.Zero)
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(dataOut.pbData);
        }
        return epwsb.ToString();
    }
}
// Test code:
class program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mstscpw mstscpw = new Mstscpw();
        string epw = mstscpw.encryptpw("password");
        Console.WriteLine("Encrypted password for \"password\" {0} characters: \r\n{1}", epw.Length, epw);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Remote Desktop Plus](http://www.donkz.nl/remotedesktopplus/) from Donkz.nl.

Feature #1:

> Login automatically from the command line.

Example:

```
rdp /v:nlmail01 /u:administrator /p:P@ssw0rd! /max
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternativly create a batch script (.bat) with the following lines:

`cmdkey /generic:"computername or IP" /user:"username" /pass:"password"
 mstsc /v:"computer name or IP"`

Note replace the IP, username and password in the script with the valid credentials.

Now run the script by simply double clicking on it.

This works.

Answer (score 0):

Well, partially correct, you cannot really edit the Microsoft Credentials easily, and the command is not `rdp`, but if you run the command `mstsc` it will correct the 'save password' issue on WinXP.

[Access Remote Desktop Via Commandline](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4487.access-remote-desktop-via-commandline.aspx)

```
mstsc [<connection file>] [/v:<server[:port]>] [/admin] [/f[ullscreen]] [/w:<width>] [/h:<height>] [/public] | [/span] [/edit "connection file"] [/migrate] [/?]
```

Just open a CMD window, type `mstsc` , put in the PC name or IP, click Options, and go on your merry way, but do a Save As... so you have a working shortcut for later.